# HTML adaptable table (width, height)

Tags: html, css, width, css-tables

I know there's a CSS solution to set up the width of a table. For example:

```
table {width: 100%; height:300px}
```

will adapt the width of the table taking the 100% of the screen but, if I insert height: 100% it doesn't work.
I want to create a table (or more tables) that fits to the screen dimensions (for smartphone, pc, ecc..).
Is there any solution?

Comment: You have to add `height: 100%` to its parent elements as well, such as `<body>` and `<html>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**just use `width: 100%;` and `height: 100vh;`**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;

}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

see Example: https://codepen.io/miladfm/pen/MGPdOL

Comment: Thanks! But now, if I'd like two tables (one up and one down) that take up 100% of the screen, what do I do? I think I have to insert height:50vh in each table so tables take 50% one and 50% the other, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Use `height: 100vh` may it work for you

Answer (score 0):

it's not necessary to use a table, you can write HTML behave as table:

```
<section style="display: table;">
 <header style="display: table-row;">
<div style="display: table-cell;"></div>
<div style="display: table-cell;"></div>
<div style="display: table-cell;"></div>
</header>
   <div style="display: table-row;">
   <div style="display: table-cell;"></div>
   <div style="display: table-cell;"></div>
   <div style="display: table-cell;"></div>
   </div>
</section>
```

and use the CSS to style it:

```
display: table                /* <table>     */
display: table-cell           /* <td>        */
display: table-row            /* <tr>        */
display: table-column         /* <col>       */
display: table-column-group   /* <colgroup>  */
display: table-footer-group   /* <tfoot>     */
display: table-header-group   /* <thead>     */
```

You might occasionally hear: tables are unsemantic. That's not true - they semantically indicate tabular data. Tables are the right choice when that is the case.
refer to [link](https://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element/)

Comment: Doing this, it will automatically set the 100% of the height?

Comment: No it will not, but it will give you the flexibility to style your code.

Answer (score 0):

**see code below:** (you can also add `margin: 0` to `body` to prevent `margin`)

```css
body{
height:100%;
}
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    height:100vh;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<body>

<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! But now, if I'd like two tables (one up and one down) that take up 100% of the screen, what do I do? I think I have to insert height:50vh in each table so tables take 50% one and 50% the other, I'm not sure.